# Why isn't scope.$watch working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please see this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sDnN5/

```
scope.$watch('points', function (value) {
    scope.console.push('scope.$watch');
});
```

for some reason this is not firing when `$scope.points` change

```
$scope.points.push(1);
```

Why?

**EDIT** To clarify:

I expect to see this:

```
events: ["scope.$watch","testUpdate()","scope.$watch","testUpdate()","scope.$watch","testUpdate()"]
```

But instead I see this:

```
events: ["scope.$watch","testUpdate()","testUpdate()","testUpdate()"]
```

Note the absence of `scope.$watch`es

Comment: You Fiddle works for me...

Comment: Please see my clarification about what I expect and what I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, add true in your attribute function watch :

```
scope.$watch('points', function (value) {
    alert('totowatch');
    scope.console.push('scope.$watch');
},true);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That does exactly what I need. What is that `true`?

Comment: deepWatch  : [defaults to false] allows all properties of a complex object to be watched. ;-)